# What is the difference between jit and autojit in numba?

Tags: python, numba

I'm confused as to what the difference is between `jit` and `autojit`.

I've read this:

http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.6/doc/userguide.html

But can't say I know feel confident in choosing between the two options. Could someone elaborate, ideally with an example.

Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I should've read this which is for the newer version of numba.

http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.15.1/tutorial_firststeps.html#compiling-a-function-with-numba-jit-using-an-explicit-function-signature

2) jit(function) -> dispatcher

```
Same as old autojit.  Create a dispatcher function object that
specialize at call site.

Example:

    @jit
    def foo(x, y):
        return x + y
```

http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.15.1/tutorial_firststeps.html#compiling-a-function-without-providing-a-function-signature-autojit-functionality

> Starting with numba version 0.12, it is possible to use numba.jit without providing a type-signature for the function. This functionality was provided by numba.autojit in previous versions of numba. The old numba.autojit hass been deprecated in favour of this signature-less version of numba.jit.

Comment: I was hoping that I would find out the difference when I found this question and answer, but I don't understand this answer. Could you elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: basically there is no difference. `autojit` used to be used and not sure what the difference used to be but now just use `jit`.

Comment: added another link which details this more. Seems like this is as of numba 0.12